# PHP error when attempting to print variables within an echo using heredoc

Tags: php, variables, echo, php-5.3, heredoc

When I try to do this:

```
var $example = "Example";
echo <<<EOT
<p>$example</p>
EOT;
```

I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   T_VAR in ..... on line ...

What is going on here?? To my knowledge this should work.

I'm using PHP 5.3.5.

Comment: Problem's not the heredoc. It's the `var`.

Comment: O_o "var"... this brings up old memories to my head. Why are you using this keyword? Why not just remove it?

Comment: `var`? like in Pascal or JavaScript... not in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no keyword `var` in PHP. Not in PHP5 anyway - it's only accepted due to backward compatibility, and is used to define class variables.

Answer (score 5):

The `var` keyword on the first line is for declaring variables in classes only. Leave it out.

Comment: And even there it's just an old leftover from PHP 4.

Answer (score 3):

remove the word var.

see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Answer (score 0):

D'oh. Removing the 'var' keyword fixed it. Thanks for the input guys!

Unfortunately however it didn't solve my actual problem. See here:

```
$param = array_merge($_REQUEST, $_FILES, $_COOKIE);

$param['example'] = "example";

example();

function example()
{
    global $param;
    echo <<<EOT
        <p>$param['example']</p>
EOT;
    return;
}
```

This time the complaint is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting
>   T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING
>   in ..... on line ...

Again, what is going on here?

Comment: Drop the quotes. i.e. write `$param[example]`. Or write `{$param['example']}`.

Comment: try surrounding the argument with curly braces: `{$param['example']}`

Comment: Thank you as well. I actually prefer that way.